# Pandasでグループごとに連番を付与する方法

Tags: python, pandas

Pandasのdataframeで、複数列の組み合わせ別に連番を付与する方法を教えていただきたいです。
具体的には、「ID」「日付」「店」の組み合わせごとの連番を、「カウント」という列を作成してそこに入れたいです。

「ID」「日付」「店」があったとして、連番を格納する「カウント」の値は、以下のイメージです。

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4],
'日': ['4/3', '4/5', '4/1', '4/1', '5/30', '5/5', '5/5', '5/5', '6/7', '5/3', '5/3', '6/7'],
'店舗': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A'],
'カウント': ['1', '2', '1', '1', '2', '1', '2', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3']})
```

ご存知の方いらっしゃいましたらアドバイスいただけるとありがたいです。

Answer (score 1):

`DataFrame.groupby` メソッドで集約した後、`grouper.group_info` を使ってナンバリングします。

前提条件は、対象のデータフレームが ID でソート、同じ ID 内では「日」でソート、同じ ID, 「日」 では「店舗」でソート済みになっている事です(ID, 「日」, 「店舗」が同一の行は連続している)。そうでない場合は誤った結果が得られるでしょう。

```
>>> ids = df.groupby(['ID']).grouper.group_info[0]
>>> ids
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])
>>> comb = df.groupby(['ID', '日', '店舗']).grouper.group_info[0]
>>> comb
array([0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

>>> count = []; nth = 0
>>> for i, c in enumerate(comb):
      if i == 0 or ids[i] != ids[i-1]:
        nth = 1
      elif c != comb[i-1]:
        nth += 1
      count += [nth]

>>> df['カウント'] = count
>>> df
    ID     日 店舗  カウント
0    1   4/3  A     1
1    1   4/5  B     2
2    2   4/1  A     1
3    2   4/1  A     1
4    2  5/30  C     2
5    3   5/5  A     1
6    3   5/5  B     2
7    3   5/5  B     2
8    3   6/7  B     3
9    4   5/3  C     1
10   4   5/3  D     2
11   4   6/7  A     3
```

Comment: grouper.group_infoは知りませんでした 。（cumsumやcumcountを使うのかと思いその可能性を探っていました・・）   

教えていただいたコードをコピペで実行してみたところ、エラーが出てしまいました。。（記載いただいたコードを、アレンジする必要がありましたか？？）
＞ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: 手元の環境は python 2.7.17rc1 + pandas 0.24.2 もしくは python 3.7.5 + pandas 0.24.2 ですが、どちらでもエラーにはなりません。元のデータフレームは質問欄にかかれているものと同じでしょうか？

Comment: `id` という変数名が python のビルトイン関数の名前と重なっていましたので `ids` に変更しました。

Comment: 元のデータフレームは、質問欄に記入したものです。再度「id」を「ids」に変更して実行するも、同様のエラーが出てしまいます。。ちなみに「count = []; nth = 0」の部分でセミコロンが入っていますが、こちらは正しいでしょうか？？

Comment: はい、セミコロンが入っていても問題ありません。ValueError はどの箇所で発生しているのでしょうか？

Comment: for文まではエラーが出ずに実行できましたが、最後、元のdfにcountを代入する一行を実行すると、次のエラーが起こってしまいます。。 raise ValueError("Length of values does not match length of index")　ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: そうなりますと、データフレームの行数と count のサイズが異なっている事になりますね。`len(count)` と `len(df.index)` の値を教えていただけますか(こちらでは両方 `12` になります)。

Comment: すみません！今一度教えていただいたコードをコピペしてみたところ、for文の最終行「count += [nth]」を誤って「nth += 1」と同じ位置にインデントしてしまっていたので、それを修正したところ、エラーなく実行できました！お騒がせしました。。ありがとうございます！